# How do you get the active element ID of an htmlarea (for instance) that has the cursor but hasn't been clicked or typed in yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I need to get active element ID and other values via a Chrome Extension.

Specific use case is creating a comment bubble in Google Docs.

If the user clicks or types in a comment bubble I can get the info via listening for mousedown and keypress (see code snippet below, which sits in a content script).

But if the user just clicks a comment icon (Google Docs, Dropbox editing etc) and a comment bubble appears, with a blinking cursor, I don't have code to pick up the active element. The cursor is there, blinking, but the user hasn't interacted with it yet.

**How do you get the active element in this case?**

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){
    activeEl = document.activeElement;
    activeTag = activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase();
    activeID = activeEl.id;
    console.log("Mmousedown and type of element is: " + activeEl.id + " / " + activeTag);
}, true);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `focus` event?

Comment: Or try focusin if you want it to buble

Comment: Focusin did it - thank you!